# Android: two spinners beside

Tags: java, android

I have price values which I want to show in 2 different spinners beside: "from" and "to", I want to have two spinners showing beside eachother, One of them will contain "from values"
and the other one "to values"

How is this possible in android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use table layout, something like this in your layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TableRow>
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/widget1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/widget2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I did not compile this or make sure it will work, this is just to give you an idea.

good luck!